# EF searching by fields from dynamic table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables that share common fields

```
class T1:IHasUserID
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    //other properties
}
class T2:IHasUserID
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    //other properties
}
class T3:IHasUserID
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    //other properties
}
```

type of entity is defined at runtime
finding by Id is easy as it's PK so I can write like this:

```
var res = (IHasUserId) dbContext.FindAsync(ctx.TableType, id)
```

but how do I search by UserId

Comment: Why do you want this? EF is an ORM and deals with entities, not tables. The *entity types* are always known in advance. `FindAsync` is only meant to retrieve objects by PK values. To search by other fields you need `Where` or methods that call `Where`, eg `FirstAsync()`, `SingleAsync()`. You could write a generic method with a type constraint on `IHasUserID`, allowing you to write `context.Set<T>().FirstAsync(x=>x.UserID==id)` but that's no better than just writing `.FirstAsync(x=>x.UserID==id)` in the calling code

Comment: If you want all the objects related to a User, the User object should have relations to them so that loading the `User` would also load the related objects you want. There wouldn't be any need for searching by UserId, just a `ctx.Users.Include(u=>u.Posts)....FirstAsync()`

Comment: that is the point entity is unknown. I did what you suggested created generic method with `context.Set<T>().FirstAsync(x=>x.UserID==id)` and run it using reflection. It works thanks.

Comment: No it's not unknown. It has to be registered to begin with. Then, since you want a specific type, you need to specify that type. No, you don't need reflection because all LINQ operators can already handle *all* types. `FirstAsync` accepts a `Func<T,bool>` so it can handle all types. The types must be configured entities though

Comment: The only reason to want to ask different types for the same condition is that either they're related to the same root. Either there's an inheritance relation, which is already supported by EF, or there's a composition relation, again supported by EF. In both cases there are no "unknown" types. If you have Employee and Manager types that both inherit from User, you can get them all by querying `Users`. EF will retrieve the specific type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if this is what you're trying to do, but to search by UserID i usually do it like this

```
var tableRow = ctx.TableType.Where(tt=> tt.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also I would add both ID and UserId in IHasUserID. This is because your T1, T2, T3 tables are extensions to IHasUserID, and should hold the variables that are common between all tables depending on it.

So like this:

```
class IHasUserID
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
}
class T1:IHasUserID
{
    //other properties
}
class T2:IHasUserID
{
    //other properties
}
class T3:IHasUserID
{
    //other properties
}
```

Comment: In other words, start rebuilding the *entities* that should be there from the start. `IHasUserId` isn't needed. `ctx.Users.Find(userId)` will work out of the box. So would `ctx.Set<T>().Find(userId)` provided `T` is a configured entity type.

Comment: @icen please upvote the answer as well if you found it helpful! :)

Answer (score -1):

thanks to all comments the way I did it I've created generic method

```
    private async ValueTask<int?> GetId<TTable>(string userId) where TTable: IHasUserID
    {
        TSagaTable res = await dbContext.Set<TSagaTable>().FirstAsync(_ => _.UserId == userId );

        return res.Id
    }
```

and run it like so

```
    public async ValueTask<int?> GetIdByUser(string kind, string userId)
    {
        Type tableType = kindProvider.GetAll().First(x => x.Kind== kind).JsonTableType;

        MethodInfo method = typeof(IdResolver).GetMethod(nameof(GetId),BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);

        return await (ValueTask<int?>) generic.Invoke(this,new object []{ userId});
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for reflection in the first place. You can pass You still haven't explained what you want to do but most likely it's already supported. If you have Employee and Manager that both inherit from User, you can retrieve any of them by querying `User`. If you want to find all Blogs, Posts related to a user, you retrieve them along with the object.

Comment: It looks like the cause of the problem is `Type tableType = kindProvider.GetAll().First(x => x.Kind== kind).JsonTableType;`. What's the purpose of this? It seems EF Core is used the wrong way entirely, as a database connection, not as an ORM. If you want to map arbitrary results, use Dapper and a SQL builder

Comment: Also, `GetById` is also wrong. If only the ID is needed, there's no reason to retrieve the entire object. `ctx.Users.Where(u=>u.UserId==id).Select(u=>u.Id).FirstAsync()` will return just the ID. The very fact so many IDs fly around  is a smell though. It seems the application is trying to do lookups based on IDs, something that *EF* is supposed to do based on relations